# Derivative of $ h(t)= \sin (\cos^{-1}t$)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse

Can someone please explain the steps/rules I need to preform to find the derivative of

$h(t)= \sin (\cos^{-1}t)$?

I tried to used the product rule, and realized it was obviously a failure.
Using the chain rule I get:

**$\frac{dy}{dx}= \cos(\cos^{-1}t)\frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$**

I know I am not finished, what am I supposed to do with this?

Comment: First, that should be dh/dt, not dy/dx. Secondly, why are you not finished? That's the derivative.

Comment: Well, the **only** thing you can apply here is the chain rule, of course: you have composition of two functions, **not** a product. You're indeed almost finished, just change that $\;-t\;$ to $\;-1\;$ and you're done.

Comment: Oops, I missed the mistake that @DonAntonio pointed out. It does need to be changed.

Comment: Okay, I see my mistake with the t needing to be 1, but I don't understand the rest of it because before coming here, I checked solutions to my book which showed: h(t)= sin (arccos t)= sqrt(1-t^2) therefore, h'(t)= [(1/2)(1-t^2)^(-1/2)][-2t]= -t/sqrt(1-t^2)

Comment: Yes, the $\;-t\;$ now appears **after** $\;\cos\arccos t=t\;$ , not *before*...

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
h'(t) &= \frac{d}{dt}\sin(\arccos t) \\
&=\cos(\arccos t) \frac{d}{dt}(\arccos t) & \text{chain rule}\\
&=\cos(\arccos t) \cdot -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} & \text{$\frac{d}{dt}(\arccos t)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$}\\
&=t \cdot -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} & \text{$\cos(\arccos t)=t$}\\
&= \frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} 
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

You can also make the observation that $h(t)=\sin(\cos^{-1}(t)) = \sqrt{1-t^2}$ and differentiate from there (do some trig to see where this observation comes from).

\begin{align}
(\sqrt{1-t^2})' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-t^2}}\times(1-t^2)'=\frac{-2t}{2\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Use the chain rule:

$$\begin{align}h'(t) &= \cos(\cos^{-1}t)\cdot\frac{d}{dt}(\cos^{-1}t)\\
&=t\cdot\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\\
&=\frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

If $\displaystyle\cos^{-1}t=u,\cos u =t$

As the [Principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) values of inverse cosine ratio lies in $\displaystyle\left[0,\pi\right]$

$\displaystyle\sin(\cos^{-1}t)=\sin u\ge0\implies \sin u=+\sqrt{1-\cos^2u}=\sqrt{1-t^2}$

Comment: This is exactly what I wasn't understanding from my book as it doesn't explain what changes are being made. I didn't make this connection, Thanks :)

Comment: For what it's worth, compositions of the form $\operatorname{trig}_1 \left( \operatorname{trig}_2^{-1} (t) \right)$, where $\operatorname{trig}_1$ and $\operatorname{trig}_2$ are any of the six trigonometric functions, are always equivalent to rational expressions, whose numerators and denominators are expressions of the form $1$, $t$, $\sqrt{1 + t^2}$, or $\sqrt{1 - t^2}$.  I call these *Pythagorean* expressions, as they form the labels of the sides of a right triangle.

Comment: The previous comment is for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the function composition, we can also re-arrange this as
$ \ \arcsin  (h) \ = \ \arccos (t) \ \ $ and use implicit differentiation (along with the known derivatives of these inverse trigonometric functions) to write

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \ [\arcsin (h)] \ = \ \frac{d}{dt} \ [\arccos (t)]   $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 \ - \ h^2}} \ \cdot \ \frac{dh}{dt} \ = \ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 \ - \ t^2}}  \ \  \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{dh}{dt} \ = \ -\frac{\sqrt{1 \ - \ h^2}}{\sqrt{1 \ - \ t^2}} \ \ . $$

But since $ \ h(t) \ = \ \sin (\arccos (t)) \ , $ we can apply the Pythagorean Identity to write (with appropriate domain restrictions)

$$ \frac{dh}{dt} \ = \ -\frac{\cos (\arccos (t))}{\sqrt{1 \ - \ t^2}} \ = \ -\frac{t}{\sqrt{1 \ - \ t^2}} \ \ . $$